# Hypergeometric solution to getting a straight series on roll of 3 dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, hypergeometric-function

Looking for a sanity check on a solution I had for obtaining a linear sequence in a single roll of 3 dice. So a $ (1,2,3) $, $ (2,3, 4) $ etc counts as a success.

The sample space is $ 6^3 $ = 216 possible dice combinations.

There are 4 possible successful combinations out of all the ways the dice can be rolled $ (1,2,3) $, $ (2,3,4) $, $ (3,4,5) $, $ (4,5,6) $ and each of these can be ordered $3!$ ways. So 24 possible successes.

Now I attempt to solve this with the hypergeometric distribution.

$ N = 216 $ - The sample space

$ k = 24 $ - Possible successes in population

$ n = 1 $ - Sample size

$ x = 1 $ - Desired successes

$ \Pr[X = 1] = \frac{\dbinom{24}{1}\!\!{\dbinom{216-24}{0}}}{\dbinom{216}{1}}  = 0.111$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but looks very strange. The probability is simply the ratio $\frac{k}{N}$.

Comment: As said above, when your "sample size" is only $1$, you do not need to use hypergeometric distribution to deal with the non-replacement issue. Of course this is a special case of it.

Comment: I overlooked the obvious, thanks!